# Change flex disclosure icon

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex-mx

At mx:Tree the folders has a folder icon and a disclosure icon(grey arrow in default style). I can easily set different folder icons with iconFunction. How can I change the disclosure icons? (I want to set different icon to each folders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this using the `disclosureClosedIcon` and `disclosureOpenIcon` styles.  You can specify a `TreeDisclosureClosed` and a `TreeDisclosureOpen` symbol in an assets.swf (Flex 3 skin style).

See the mx:Tree [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has good example for your question (See **"Using the setItemIcon() method"** section from link below ) - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d80.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf66ce9-7fea or short documentation about [setItemIcon()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Tree.html#setItemIcon())